# Visualize cosets of $\left<(0,1)\right>$ partition $C_3 \times C_3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, intuition, visualization

[image]

Page 105 says - A careful look at Figure 6.9 reveals that the cosets of $\left< \, (0,1) \,\right>$ partition $C_3 \times  C_3$.

How is this true? The picture shows $gH = left picture =  (1,0)\left< \, (0,1) \,\right>= \{(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)\} \\ = right picture = \left< \, (0,1) \, \right>(1,0) = Hg $.
But this is not all of $C_3 \times  C_3$ therefore not a partition?

The book hasn't introduced quotient groups or normal subgroups still.
This is from Nathan Carter page 104 Visual Group Theory.

Comment: Three questions in 1/2 hour on the same subject exactly...are you giving yourself time enough to assimilate?

Comment: @DonAntonio I spent the past couple of days going through this. I am only posting at once what I do not understand. I will stew over this more.

Answer (score 0):

The partition consists of $G/\langle (0,1) \rangle = \{(0,0)\langle (0,1) \rangle,\  (1,0)\langle (0,1) \rangle,\  (2,0)\langle (0,1) \rangle\}$. He never says that $gH$ is a partition of $G$; it is an element of the partiton, that, in this case, is $\{g^0H,\ gH, \ g^2H\}$.

Comment: thanks. can you please rewrite your answer without quotient groups? Book hasn't introduced them.